# Android OpenGL ES Textures Not Showing On Samsung Phones

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I'm a long time reader, first time poster, and I recently found out my Android game has an odd issue. I use my HTC Desire Z to test my game along with the emulator and all is working fine, but my friends recently told me that on Samsung handsets (at least Galaxy S2 and regular Galaxy have the symptom) the screen just stays white. After a little debugging with a friend's handset I was able to find out that the game runs correctly, but the textures aren't just showing up. I tried searching about the problem, but didn't really spot anything helpful.

The textures are .png, square and POT. Here are the relevant code bits starting with bitmap loading:

```
private boolean LoadTextures(GL10 gl) {
   if(DEBUG)
      Log.d(TAG, "Loading textures.");
   bitmaps[0] = R.raw.game;
   bitmaps[1] = R.raw.splash;
   bitmaps[2] = R.raw.menu;
   bitmaps[3] = R.raw.font01;
   bitmaps[4] = R.raw.bg;
   bitmaps[5] = R.raw.gameover;
   bitmaps[6] = R.raw.helpc;
   bitmaps[7] = R.raw.helptag;      

   gl.glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, textures, 0);

   for(int i=0; i<NUM_TEXTURES; i++) {
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), bitmaps[i]);
      if(bitmap == null)
      {
         if(DEBUG)
         {
            Log.w(TAG, "Bitmap decoding failed, aborting.");
            return false;
         }
      }

      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                         GL10.GL_LINEAR);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                         GL10.GL_LINEAR);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                         GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                         GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
      bitmap.recycle();
   }
return true;
}
```

My onSurfaceCreated function:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
   gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  
   if(DEBUG) 
      Log.d(TAG, "GLRenderer: Surface created.");
}
```

My onSurfaceChanged function

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
   if(LoadTextures(gl)) // load textures
   {
      if(DEBUG)
         Log.d(TAG, "Textures loaded succesfully.");
   }
   else
   {
      if(DEBUG)
         Log.w(TAG, "Texture loading failed.");
   }
   gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   gl.glOrthof(-width/2f, width/2f, -height/2f, height/2f, -1, 1);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
   gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
   gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);     
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
   gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   Log.d(TAG, "Set GL modes succesfully.");
}
```

Relevant drawing from OnDrawFrame:

```
gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, i.GetBuffers().GetVertexBuffer());      
gl.glTranslatef(i.GetXCoordinate(),i.GetYCoordinate(), i.GetZCoordinate());
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i.GetBuffers().GetTextureId()]);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, i.GetBuffers().GetTextureBuffer());
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, i.GetBuffers().GetIndicesCount(),   
                  GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, i.GetBuffers().GetIndexBuffer());                          
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Any tips as to why this doesn't work on Samsung phones will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have glGetError anywhere?